# Simple example on do syntax transformed to >>= syntax

Tags: haskell

How can `reverse2lines` transformed into the using `>>=` syntax ? Just like `addOneInt` is transformed into  `addOneInt'`?

```
addOneInt :: IO () 
addOneInt = do line <- getLine
               putStrLn (show (1 + read line :: Int))      


addOneInt' :: IO ()
addOneInt' = getLine >>= \line ->
             putStrLn (show ( 1 + read line :: Int))  

reverse2lines :: IO () 
reverse2lines = 
 do line1 <- getLine 
    line2 <- getLine
    putStrLn (reverse line2) 
    putStrLn (reverse line1)
```

Please also consider reading the follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090948/nested-do-syntax) and its valuable answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could safely deduce it from what you already know. Start by fully parenthesizing your `addOneInt'`:

```
addOneInt' = getLine >>= (\line ->
             putStrLn (show (1 + read line :: Int)) )
```

Next, you `reverse2lines` can be equivalently written as

```
reverse2lines = 
 do { line1 <- getLine ;
      do { line2 <- getLine ;
           do { putStrLn (reverse line2) ;
                do { putStrLn (reverse line1) } } } }
```

Applying the one-step transformation that you already used for `addOneInt`, as much times as needed, you'd get

```
reverse2lines' :: IO ()
reverse2lines' = 
    getLine  >>=  (\line1 ->
      getLine  >>=  (\line2 ->
        putStrLn (reverse line2)  >>
          putStrLn (reverse line1) ) )
```

Syntactically, the parentheses around lambda expressions can be omitted, but writing them explicitly here helps to clarify and make obvious the nested structure of these functions,  especially if we'd line up the indentation.

Full translation arranges for the monad's `fail` function to be called on pattern mismatch, but since the variable patterns (`line1`, `line2`) are irrefutable, this translation is in fact exact.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, is it possible to formulate `reverse2lines` with only `>>=` ? Without `>>` ?

Comment: yes, `m >> n === m >>= (\_ -> n)`. For some monads it is even defined this way; for others a more efficient specific code is possible for `>>`.

Comment: nah, it's very simple: you just replace `>>` with `>>= \_ ->`. :)

Comment: So basically every new command in the sequence goes into the belly of a new lambda ?

Comment: (sorry, I was offline) yes, exactly. That's the special thing about the monads, too: because they are created nested, each can branch on its input, and decide which of the possibilities to take (as in `if pred then do this else do that`). You could make them non-nested too, with explicit use of bind (`>>=`), but then you'd have to specifically arrange for passing the needed parts of info along the line, unlike in nested setting where the outer variables are just available in the inner functions.

Comment: There some slight logical inconstancy with this answer as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090948/nested-do-syntax?noredirect=1#comment35293452_23090948

Comment: @jhegedus I think my answer here and Tikhon's there are exactly equivalent. So at least there isn't any inconsistency, thanks goodness. You just wanted additional explanation about why the nested do expressions were equivalent to the non-nested one. Yes, I didn't try to explain it, I used it as a self-evident equivalency, mostly because `do {one}` == `one`. So `do {one; do {another}}` == `do {one; another}`. Admittedly, this doesn't cover the `do {one; do{ two; three}}` == `do { one; two; three }`. I skipped that part. :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer, indeed there is nothing incorrect about the answer, I understand that now. I am quite a beginner in Haskell and get confused easily but thanks to SOF I can get un-confused again :)

Comment: I see now what you meant by inconsistency. that equivalency indeed is a consequence of the `do` translation rules; so without knowing them you indeed had no way of knowing about that equivalency, even if it looks so self-evident to me. Good for you for insisting on proper chain of evidence and derivation! :) -- for me, it was an application of recursive thinking, but the fact that it indeed *can* be applied here is a separate issue. (re: [do { e; *stmts* } == e >> do { *stmts* } == do { e; do { *stmts* }}](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) etc. ).

Comment: @jhegedus and I'm not the only one to make that leap: [haskellwiki page on monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws) too shows what amounts to `do { a; do { b; c}}` == `do {a; b; c;}`, under "associativity" in "practical meaning" subsection, without any explicit justification.  :)

Comment: I just have this deep need to understand things from first principles :) but now is all sorted out.

Answer (score 4):

Statements of type `x <- m` can be translated as `m >>= \x -> ...`, and statements in which the return value isn't bound like `m` can be translated as `m >> ...`

```
reverse2lines :: IO () 
reverse2lines = getLine 
                >>= \line1 -> getLine 
                >>= \line2 -> putStrLn (reverse line2)
                >> putStrLn (reverse line1)
```

The translation isn't exact - the `fail` monad function complicates things a little. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705266/why-does-my-haskell-do-notation-break-when-i-try-to-desugar-it/22705851#22705851), but as far as I know it's irrelevant when dealing with the `IO` monad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code from Will's very nice answer using only `>>=` :

```
reverse2lines' :: IO () 
reverse2lines' = 
    getLine >>= (\line1 -> 
        getLine >>= (\line2 -> 
            putStrLn (reverse line2) >>= (\_ ->
               putStrLn (reverse line1) )))
```

Lesson learned : the sequencing in `do` corresponds simply to nesting of lambda expressions.