# Nested do syntax

Tags: haskell, monads

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909281/simple-example-on-do-syntax-transformed-to-syntax) question Will's answer states that the following code (let's call it `code A`):

```
reverse2lines :: IO () 
reverse2lines = 
 do line1 <- getLine 
    line2 <- getLine
    putStrLn (reverse line2) 
    putStrLn (reverse line1)
```

can be transformed into the following (let's call it `code B`) :

```
reverse2lines = 
 do { line1 <- getLine ;
      do { line2 <- getLine ;
           do { putStrLn (reverse line2) ;
                do { putStrLn (reverse line1) } } } }
```

I am confused.
I understand, for example, that

```
addOneInt :: IO () 
addOneInt = do line <- getLine
               putStrLn (show (1 + read line :: Int))
```

can be transformed into:

```
addOneInt' :: IO ()
addOneInt' = getLine >>= \line ->
             putStrLn (show ( 1 + read line :: Int))
```

But I don't understand how the nested `do` transformation works. In other words, I don't understand how one arrives from `code A` to `code B` ? What are the rules governing this transformation ?

Where are these rules described / explained / specified ?

Could someone please explain what is going on here with this (`codeA` to `codeB`) transformation ?

For example, what does `do { command1; do {command2 } }` mean ? How should I interpret that ? What is its definition ?

In other words,

what is the difference between

`do {command1;command2}` and

`do {command1; do {command2}}` ?

Furthermore, what is the difference between

`do {command1; do{command2};command3}` and

`do {command1;do {command2; do {command3}}}` ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: A hint, `do single_expr` is exactly the same as `single_expr`.  So `do { cmd1; cmd2 }` and `do { cmd1; do {cmd2} }` are identical.  To put it another way, the `hlint` tool that checks your code for stylistic problems will flag `do single_expr` as a redundant `do`, and tell you to remove it since it is unnecessary.

Comment: The next thing to remember is that `do { cmd1; cmd2 }` is the same as `cmd1 >> cmd2`, which is the same as `cmd1 >>= \_ -> cmd2`.  So that means that `do { cmd1; do { cmd2 } } === do { cmd1; cmd2 } === cmd1 >> cmd2 === cmd1 >>= \_ -> cmd2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just treat the `do` expressions completely separately: nesting them does not change how they get desugared. For your to example, we can start with the bottom line:

```
reverse2lines = 
 do { line1 <- getLine ;
      do { line2 <- getLine ;
           do { putStrLn (reverse line2) ;
                putStrLn (reverse line1) } } }
```

then the next one:

```
reverse2lines = 
 do { line1 <- getLine ;
      do { line2 <- getLine ;
           putStrLn (reverse line2) >> putStrLn (reverse line1) } }
```

which is, in fact, just like:

```
reverse2lines = 
 do { line1 <- getLine ;
      do { line2 <- getLine ;
           putStrLn (reverse line2)
           putStrLn (reverse line1) } }
```

then we can turn the inner remaining `do` into a lambda:

```
reverse2lines = 
 do { line1 <- getLine ;
      getLine >>= \ line2
       putStrLn (reverse line2) >>
       putStrLn (reverse line1)  }
```

And then, if we go backwards, we see that it's the same as just:

```
reverse2lines = 
 do { line1 <- getLine ;
      line2 <- getLine ;
      putStrLn (reverse line2) ;
      putStrLn (reverse line1)  }
```

So, as you can see by going through the whole example, the nested version is the same as the flat version. In fact, if you just look at the rules for desugaring `do` expressions (and we've seen the important ones), you'll see that nesting them like this does not change anything.

In fact, this is pretty natural because the way `do` is desugared is defined recursively: each time we desugar a single line, we recurse on all the lines following it as if they were another `do` expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the original answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909281/simple-example-on-do-syntax-transformed-to-syntax) Will said that `code A` can be directly rewritten to `code B` without using the `do` to `>>=` desugaring (he later desugared `code B` to `>>=` syntax). This is what confused me. So you say that there is no way to get from `code A` to `code B` without the use of the `do` to `>>=` desugaring rule ?

Comment: @jhegedus: You could just have a rule that is something like `do { x <- m; do { ... } }` ==> `do { x <- m; ... }`. That wouldn't *explicitly* use the desugaring.

Comment: @jhegedus: I'm not really sure what you mean by your question. Anyhow, since the rules for desugaring are recursive--at each step, the rest of the lines are treated like a new do-expression to desugar--you could skip the `>>=` bits. You can always nest `do` expressions like this. I just thought they were illustrative.

Comment: In other words, in Will's answer it is implied that the code transformation from `code A` to `code B` has nothing to do with the `do` desugaring rule.

Comment: @jhegedus I'm not totally sure what you mean. `do` notation gets turned into `>>=` and `>>` internally by the compiler, so it can't really ever be considered totally independent from those methods.

Comment: @David Young : But that would implicitly still need the desugaring rule right ?

Comment: I see, thanks, I think I got confused by the accepted answer in the original question. That answer might be perhaps a little bit misleading.

Comment: @jhegedus Well, yes because that is how `do` is defined. To me, this is like asking something like "can I expand '(x + y)*(a + b)' without using the distributive law." Yeah, you can just use the FOIL operation, but FOIL works because of the distributive law.

Comment: So here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909281/simple-example-on-do-syntax-transformed-to-syntax Will goes from `code A` to `code B` and then uses the desugaring on `code B` to get to a form which uses no `do` at all. This is logically misleading. It implies that one can go from `codeA` to `codeB` **without** making use of the desugaring rule but now I understand that one has to use -at least implicitly - the desugaring rule to get from `codeA` to `codeB`.

Comment: @jhegedus That doesn't seem very misleading to me at all. For one thing, he never said that you *didn't* need to desugar it to show that they are equivalent. All he said is that those two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: I see. Ok. Perhaps I accept it again then because that is still the best answer. I have to admit that I am quite a beginner in Haskell and get confused easily but it's great that I can get clarification on SOF :)