# Add action without changing result to refactor do-notation

Tags: haskell, refactoring, pointfree, do-notation

I want to sequentially compose two monad actions in Haskell, discarding any value produced by the second, and passing the argument to both actions. Currently I'm using a do-block like this:

```
ask = do
  result <- getLine
  putStrLn result
  return result
```

I was hoping to write this a little more point free and neat, so I tried this:

```
ask' = getLine <* putStrLn
```

However, this doesn't even type check and the problem is that [`<*`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42-) does not transfer the result of the first action to the second. I want to chain the actions like [`>>=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-) does, but not change the result. The type should be `(a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> (a -> m b)`, but [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+m+b%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+m+c%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+m+b%29) yields no suitable results. What would be an operator to achieve this function composition?

Comment: So you want `getLine >>= \x -> putStrLn x >> return x` in point free style.  Have you asked lambdabot? It says `liftM2 (>>) putStrLn return =<< getLine`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson It seems like Lambdabot found almost the exact function that OP wanted! `flip (liftM2 (>>)) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> (a -> m b)` - the actual type is slightly more generalized so it is somewhat hard to see.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thank you, I asked the `pointfree` command line tool, and it could not handle `do`, so I gave up. I ended up using `ask = getLine >>= liftM2 (>>) putStrLn return`, which looks okay, thanks again! You can put this into an answer if you want, then I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a tendency, if you use one value in two different places it probably *is* a good idea to give it a name in a clear `do` block, rather than pressing on pointless style.

The abstract concept of splitting up information flow to different actions is captured by [cartesian monoidal categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_monoidal_category), known to Haskellers as [arrows](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html). In your case, you're basically working in the `IO` Kleisli category:

```
import Prelude hiding (id)
import Control.Arrow

ask' :: Kleisli IO () String
ask' = Kleisli (\()->getLine) >>> (putStrLn &&& id) >>> arr snd
```

I don't think it's a good idea to write such code.

Comment: You're right, it is probably not a very good idea. The arrows look really complicated. I'm not sure if the solution with `liftM2` in clear enough or confusing?

Comment: The problem with `liftM2(>>)` is that it mixes two different monads (`(a->)` and `IO`) in a really quite convoluted way. If you do something like that, better do it properly with `ReaderT`, but that's only worth it if you're reading the same value from a whole bunch of places.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to sequentially compose two monad actions in Haskell, discarding any value produced by the second, and passing the argument to both actions.

This sounds to me like a `Reader`—the function type `r -> m a` is isomorphic to `ReaderT r m a`, and the monad works by implicitly plugging in the same `r` value into all the "holes."  So for example:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Reader

example :: IO String
example = getLine >>= discarding putStrLn

discarding :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> a -> m a
discarding action = runReaderT (ReaderT action *> ask)
```

The operator you want is then something like:

```
action `thingy` extra = action >>= discarding extra
```

But of course `discarding` has a simpler implementation:

```
discarding :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> a -> f a
discarding action a = action a *> return a
```

...so in the end I think this is really code golf.  But in a more complex program where this is a common pattern at a larger scale it might be worth a shot.  Basically, if you have:

```
a0 :: r -> m a0
a1 :: r -> m a1
   .
   .
   .
an :: r -> m an
```

Then it follows that:

```
ReaderT a0 :: ReaderT r m a0
ReaderT a1 :: ReaderT r m a1
   .
   .
   .
ReaderT an :: ReaderT r m an
```

And then:

```
runReaderT (ReaderT a0 <* ReaderT a1 <* ... <* ReaderT an) :: r -> m a0
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, in this particular case (the `IO`) monad, you could also abuse [`bracket`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:bracket) for this purpose:

```
bracket getLine putStrLn return
```

But I strongly discourage it, as this will be much less readable than the original `do`-notation block, it's just ugly.

As already mentioned, in this particular case naming the result seems the best way.

See also [Should do-notation be avoided in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16726659/1333025)