# Haskell Errors Binding a CSV File to a Handle

Tags: csv, haskell, functional-programming, io-monad, do-notation

So I was writing a small toybox of utility functions for CSV files and throughout testing the functions I'd been binding the file by hand with

```
table' <- parseCSVFromFile filepath
```

but (from `Text.CSV`)

```
parseCSVFromFile :: FilePath -> IO (Either parsec-3.1.9:Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError CSV)
```

and so I had to write a quick line to strip off this either error csv crap

```
stripBare csv = head $ rights $ flip (:) [] csv
```

and redefine it as `table = stripBare table'`. After this, list functions work on the csv files contents and life goes on

(Digression: Surprisingly there isn't a direct `Either a b -> b` function in `Data.Either`. So I used `Data.Either.rights :: [Either a b] -> [b]`)

I wanted to do the work of undressing the csv type and binding it to a handle in one shot. Something like

```
table = stripBare $ table' <- parseCSVFromFile filepath
```

but this gives a parse error on (`<-`) saying I may be missing a `do`... then

```
table = stripBare $ do table' <- parseCSVFromFile filepath
```

yells at me saying that the last statement in a `do` block must be an expression.

What am I doing wrong?

As a separate curiosity, I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726659/should-do-notation-be-avoided-in-haskell) that

do notation in Haskell desugars in a pretty simple way.

```
do
  x <- foo
  e1 
  e2
  ...
```

turns into

```
 foo >>= \x ->
 do
   e1
   e2
```

I find this attractive and tried the following line which gave me a type error

```
*Toy> :type (parseCSVFromFile "~/.csv") >>= \x -> x

<interactive>:1:52: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Either
                             parsec-3.1.9:Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError'
                     with `IO'
      Expected type: IO CSV
        Actual type: Either parsec-3.1.9:Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError CSV
    * In the expression: x
      In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `\ x -> x'
      In the expression:
        (parseCSVFromFile "~/.csv") >>= \ x -> x
```

Comment: It's not surprising that `Either a b -> b` doesn't exist. If you have an `a` but no `b`, which `b` would you produce?

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. Lists allow for absence @molbdnilo

Answer (score 0):

Code such as

```
head $ rights $ flip (:) [] csv
```

is dangerous. You are exploiting the partiality of `head` to hide the fact that `csv` might be a `Left something`. We can rewrite it as

```
= head $ rights $ (:) csv []
= head $ rights [csv]
= case csv of
     Left _  -> error "Left found!"
     Right x -> x
```

Usually it's better to handle the `Left` case directly in the `do` IO block. Something like: (pseudo code follows)

```
foo :: String -> IO ()
foo filepath = do
   table' <- parseCSVFromFile filepath
   case table' of
      Left err -> do
         putStrLn "Error in parsing CSV"
         print err
         moreErrorHandlingHere
      Right table -> do
         putStrLn "CSV loaded!"
         use table
```