# Is it possible to implement MaybeT with Applicative only?

Tags: haskell

After revisiting my `MaybeT` excercise I got warning that I should also have `Applicative` instance. I tried to implement it but got stuck as I cannot find way to apply `m x` to `m f` with `Applicative m`. Do I need `Monad m`?

```
newtype MaybeT m x = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe x) }

instance Functor m => Functor (MaybeT m) where
  fmap f m = MaybeT $ fmap z $ runMaybeT m where
    z (Just x) = Just $ f x
    z Nothing = Nothing

instance Applicative m => Applicative (MaybeT m)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you do need `Monad`. Basically, if you have

```
f :: MaybeT m (a -> b)
x :: MaybeT m a
```

and if, when evaluating `f <*> x`, running the unwrapped `f` in `m` returns a `Nothing`, then the action for `x` shouldn't run at all - but you cannot achieve that without using that `m` is a `Monad`, since `Applicative` combinators intuitively always run all the subactions.

By the way, the simplest way to generate an `Applicative` just to satisfy the new AMP requirement, is to use

```
import Control.Monad (ap)

instance Applicative ... where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

For `Functor` you can either use `fmap = liftM`, or the `DeriveFunctor` extension.

Answer (score 3):

`MaybeT` could be defined as

```
newtype Compose f g x = Composed (f (g x))
newtype MaybeT m x = MaybeT (Compose m Maybe x)
```

and applicatives do [compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040844/applicatives-compose-monads-dont). Hence you can write an applicative instance for `MaybeT` like this:

```
instance Applicative m => Applicative (MaybeT m) where
  pure = MaybeT . pure . Just
  f <*> x = MaybeT $ (<*>) <$> runMaybeT f <*> runMaybeT x
```

**EDIT**

As @Ørjan Johansen and @dfeuer explain, this is not a true instance for the `MaybeT` transformer, since the definition of `(<*>)` violates the `f <*> x == ap f x` law. Here is an example:

```
test :: MaybeT IO ()
test = MaybeT (return Nothing) <*> MaybeT (putStrLn "test" >> return Nothing)

main = runMaybeT test
```

This code prints `test` with my wrong definition and doesn't print anything with the right one.

Comment: The problem with this, as Ørjan Johansen explains in their answer, is that it doesn't short-circuit as expected—`runMaybeT x` will be run even if `runMaybeT f` produces `Nothing`. Of course, your application may not care, but this is incompatible with the `Monad` instance of `MaybeT m`. The laws for the classes specify that (at least "morally"), `(<*>)=ap`. So if you use this `Applicative` instance, you must use a matching `Monad` instance as well.

Comment: Er ... forget that deleted comment. I do think you probably should remove/modify the bit about "strictness", since this isn't a strictness issue, per se, although it can affect strictness.

Comment: @dfeuer, I haven't seen a comment about strictness, that's just my understanding of what's going on. The second argument of `(<*>)` is forced, while it shouldn't. Could you explain, what is wrong?

Comment: Well, as your own example indicates, the issue is not that a thunk is *forced*, but rather that a monadic action is *executed*.

Comment: @dfeuer, I confused two concepts. Thanks again.