# Joining Nested Monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I am using `FRP.Sodium` and I have an object of type `IO (Behavior (IO (Behavior)))`. I need to convert that object to type `IO (Behavior)`, using something akin to a nested `join`. Is this possible using Sodium functions? Is there a more general solution for `a (b (a (b c))) -> a (b c))`?

Comment: The non-existence of the general solution is discussed in [Applicatives compose, monads don't](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7040844/414413).

Comment: @Cirdec Yes, that offers a very comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an obvious way to do so. You could cobble together something with the right type using functions like [`sample`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sodium/docs/FRP-Sodium-Context.html#v:sample) and [`sync`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sodium/docs/FRP-Sodium-Context.html#v:sync) or [`updates`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sodium/docs/FRP-Sodium-Context.html#v:updates) and [`executeSyncIO/executeAsyncIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sodium/docs/FRP-Sodium-Context.html#t:ContextIO), but it probably wouldn't obey the `Monad` laws.

There isn't a more general solution for `a (b (a (b c))) -> a (b c))`, but there is if `b` is [`Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html#t:Traversable), which lets you rearrange things into `a (a (b (b c)))` by [traversing](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequenceA) the outer `b`.

Comment: I hadn't even considered `traverse`, that's just what I was looking for.