# Why do monads not compose in scala

Tags: scala, monads, higher-kinded-types

Why do monads not compose when a Monad is an Applicative and an Applicative is a Functor. You see this inheritance chain in many articles on the web ( Which i have gone through ). But when Functors and Applicatives compose why do Monads break this ?

Can someone provide a simple example in scala which demonstrates this issue ? I know this is asked a lot but kind of hard to understand without a simple example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applicatives compose, monads don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040844/applicatives-compose-monads-dont)

Comment: This is haskell answer not for scala

Comment: Check out the [answer by Conal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7070339/108915). It is language agnostic. Monads are a mathematical concept and they do not differ between languages.

Comment: I know but i think its not really usefull to guide people to learn another language with another weired syntax to get this question answered. Most of this Monad tuturials are written in haskell ( which is just hard to read if you are not familiar with it ) and also many questions here on SO. But i explicitly asked for a nice explanation in scala on that specific problem. I am sure many people would appreciate that. So this question just becomes another redirect to something else ...

Comment: You didn't read the linked answer, but wrote 5 lines of complaints. The answer is shorter than your comment and **doesn't contain a single line of Haskell**.

Comment: Then again, he asked for **code** demonstrating the problem, not for an abstract answer. And he asked for **scala** code. That's a reasonable thing to ask. It's often easier to understand something with a concrete example, and only then can you really generalize this knowledge.

Comment: I really did some research before i asked this question. And the linked answer by Conal says **Monads do compose, but the result might not be a monad**. This is hard to understand without any example.

Comment: @ziggystar “language-agnostic mathematical concepts” only in theory, hehe. How about all those Functors being actually Endofunctors, and Monads being Strong Monads by default in Haskell/Scala, while I guess some esoteric “languages of space” (with topoi and s***) implement them as they actually are.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, let's start with a simple problem. Let's say, we need to get a sum of two integers, each wrapped in both `Future` and `Option`. Let's take `cats` library in order to resemble Haskell’s standard library definitions with Scala-syntax.

If we use monad approach (aka `flatMap`), we need:

- both `Future` and `Option` should have `Monad` instances defined over them
- we also need monadic transformer `OptionT` which will work only for `Option` (precisely `F[Option[T]]`)

So, here is the code (let's forget about for-comprehension and lifting to make it simpler):

```
val fa = OptionT[Future, Int](Future(Some(1)))
val fb = OptionT[Future, Int](Future(Some(2)))
fa.flatMap(a => fb.map(b => a + b)) //note that a and b are already Int's not Future's
```

if you look at `OptionT.flatMap` sources:

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => OptionT[F, B])(implicit F: Monad[F]): OptionT[F, B] =
  flatMapF(a => f(a).value)

def flatMapF[B](f: A => F[Option[B]])(implicit F: Monad[F]): OptionT[F, B] =
  OptionT(F.flatMap(value)(_.fold(F.pure[Option[B]](None))(f)))
```

You'll notice that the code is pretty specific to `Option`'s internal logic and structure (`fold`, `None`). Same problem for `EitherT`, `StateT` etc.

Important thing here is that there is no `FutureT` defined in cats, so you can compose `Future[Option[T]]`, but can't do that with `Option[Future[T]]` (later I'll show that this problem is even more generic).

On the other hand, if you choose composition using `Applicative`, you'll have to meet only one requirement:

- both `Future` and `Option` should have `Applicative` instances defined over them

You don't need any special transformers for `Option`, basically cats library provides `Nested` class that works for any `Applicative` (let's forget about applicative builder's sugar to simplify understanding):

```
val fa = Nested[Future, Option, Int](Future(Some(1)))
val fb = Nested[Future, Option, Int](Future(Some(1)))
fa.map(x => (y: Int) => y + x).ap(fb)
```

Let's swap Option and Future:

```
val fa = Nested[Option, Future, Int](Some(Future(1)))
val fb = Nested[Option, Future, Int](Some(Future(1)))
fa.map(x => (y: Int) => y + x).ap(fb)
```

Works!

So yes Monad is Applicative, `Option[Future[T]]` is still a monad (on `Future[T]` but not on `T` itself) but it allows you to operate only with `Future[T]` not `T`. In order to "merge" `Option` with `Future` layers - you have to define monadic transformer `FutureT`, in order to merge `Future` with `Option` - you have to define `OptionT`. And, `OptionT` is defined in cats/scalaz, but not `FutureT`.

In general (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7041026/1809978)):

> Unfortunately, our real goal, composition of monads, is rather more
>   difficult. .. In fact, we can actually prove that, in a certain sense,
>   there is no way to construct a join function with the type above using
>   only the operations of the two monads (see the appendix for an outline
>   of the proof). It follows that the only way that we might hope to form
>   a composition is if there are some additional constructions linking
>   the two component

And this composition is not even necessary commutative (swappable) as I demonstrated for `Option` and `Future`.

As an exercise, you can try to define `FutureT`'s flatMap:

```
def flatMapF[B](f: A => F[Future[B]])(implicit F: Monad[F]): FutureT[F, B] = 
   FutureT(F.flatMap(value){ x: Future[A] =>
      val r: Future[F[Future[B]] = x.map(f)
      //you have to return F[Future[B]] here using only f and F.pure, 
      //where F can be List, Option whatever
   })
```

basically the problem with such implementation is that you have to "extract" value from r which is impossible here, assuming you can't extract value from `Future` (there is no comonad defined on it) at least in a "non-blocking" context (like ScalaJs). This basically means that you can't "swap" `Future` and `F`, like `Future[F[Future[B]] => F[Future[Future[B]`. The latter is a natural transformation (morphism between functors), so that explains the first comment on [this general answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7041026/1809978):

> you can compose monads if you can provide a natural transformation swap : N M a -> M N a

`Applicative`s however don't have such problems - you can easily compose them, but keep in mind that result of composition of two `Applicatives` may not be a monad (but will always be an applicative). `Nested[Future, Option, T]` is not a monad on `T`, regardless that both `Option` and `Future` are monads on `T`. Putting in simple words [Nested as a class](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/Nested.scala) doesn't have `flatMap`.

It would be also helpful to read:

- http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/applicative.html
- http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/apply.html
- http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/monad.html
- http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/optiont.html

Putting it all together (`F` and `G` are monads)

- `F[G[T]]` is a monad on `G[T]`, but not on `T`
- `G_TRANSFORMER[F, T]` required in order to get a monad on `T` from `F[G[T]]`.
- there is no `MEGA_TRANSFORMER[G, F, T]` as such transformer can't be build on top of monad - it requires additional operations defined on `G` (it seems like comonad on `G` should be enough)
- every monad (including `G` and `F`) is applicative, but not every applicative is a monad
- in theory `F[G[T]]` is an applicative over both `G[T]` and `T`. However scala requires to create `NESTED[F, G, T]` in order to get composed applicative on `T` (which is implemented in cats library).
- `NESTED[F, G, T]` is applicative, but not a monad

That means you can compose `Future x Option` (aka `Option[Future[T]]`) to one single monad (coz `OptionT` exists), but you can't compose `Option x Future` (aka `Future[Option[T]]`) without knowing that Future is something else besides being a monad (even though they’re inherently applicative functors - applicative is not enough to neither build a monad nor monad transformer on it) . Basically:

- `OptionT` can be seen as non-commutative binary operator defined as `OptionT: Monad[Option] x Monad[F] -> OptionT[F, T]; for all Monad[F], T; for some F[T]`. Or in general: `Merge: Monad[G] x Monad[F] -> Monad[Merge]; for all T, Monad[F]; but only for **some of Monad[G]**, some F[T], G[T]`;
- you can compose any two applicatives into one single applicative `Nested: Applicative[F] x Applicative[G] -> Nested[F, G]; for all Applicative[F], Applicative[G], T; for some F[T], G[T]`,
- but you can compose any two monads (inherently functors) only into one *applicative* (but not into monad).

Answer (score 1):

Tony Morris gave a talk on monad transformers that explains this precise issue very well.

http://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/monad-transformers/

He uses haskell, but the examples are easily translatable to scala.

Comment: I want to avoid this haskell syntax because its just more hard to read especially for beginners on this topic! So i would prefer a simple scala sample which is understandable. Thx

Comment: Perhaps you should try writing a compose function for Functors, then attempt to write one for Monads - it'll give you a good insight.

Comment: This is a good resource, and a summary of the relevant parts would be a good answer, but on their own links to external resources should be comments, not answers.