# Option generator in for comprehension forces other generators to be Option?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

The first for expression is the base example. The 2nd for-expr introduces a slight variation which I thought would yield the same output. But failed with a compilation error. What is the reason and how to fix?

```
for {
    n <- List(1,2)
    c <- "ABC"
} yield s"$c$n"
//res0: List[String] = List(A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2)

for {
    opt <- List(None, Some(1), None, None, Some(2), None)
    n <- opt
    c <- "ABC"
} yield s"$c$n"
//Error:(14, 5) type mismatch;
//found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String]
//required: Option[?]
//  c <- "ABC"
//     ^
```

Comment: In this case yes because the second extractor is like a `flatMap` so you need to return an option.
For clarity, you are able to extract on "ABC" in the first case because of an implicit conversion, so that thing becomes a list and it compiles, in the second case "ABC" is not implicitly converted to option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reply to the title question: yes, the first generator "sets the mood" for the whole for-expression. Note that for-expressions like the ones above are *desugared* into calls to `flatMap`s and a final `map` (plus `withFilter` for guards).

In your case, the first for-expression is *desugared* into the following expression:

```
List(1, 2).flatMap(n => "ABC".map(c => s"$c$n"))
```

This can work because `Predef` (which is implicitly imported in every Scala program) provides an implicit conversion of a `String` to a `Seq[Char]`.

```
val implicitlyConverted: Seq[Char] = "ABC"
```

Thus, it type checks an run as planned.

Now let's give a look at how the second for-expressions is *desugared*:

```
List(None, Some(1), None, None, Some(2), None).flatMap(opt => opt.flatMap(n => "ABC".map(c => s"$c$n")))
```

Again, we have the same type error as above, if we break the expression into several lines we may see the issue a little bit better:

```
List(None, Some(1), None, None, Some(2), None).flatMap {
  opt =>
    opt.flatMap {
      n =>
        "ABC".map {
          c =>
            s"$c$n"
        }
    }
}
```

This gives us the following error:

```
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String]
 required: Option[?]
                      "ABC".map {
                                ^
```

The second `flatMap` expects an `Option[_]` as a result, while the `map` within (`"ABC".map(...)`) returns an `IndexedSeq[String]`.

So, this was the reason. How do we fix this? The easiest solution probably involves using a guard and forcibly extracting the value within the `Option`, like this:

```
for {
  n <- List(None, Some(1), None, None, Some(2), None)
  c <- "ABC" if n.isDefined
} yield s"$c${n.get}"
```

A more general way to solve this particular issue involves monad transformers, because the root of the issue is that monads do not compose; the issue is very wide and complex and perhaps [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39542127/3314107) may give you a more general answer.

Comment: The academic quality of the answer is above expectation. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Polymerase Thanks, I'm glad I've been helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to "fix" it is to change the order:

```
for {
    opt <- List(None, Some(1), None, None, Some(2), None)
    c <- "ABC"
    n <- opt
} yield s"$c$n"
//> List[String] = List(A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2)
```

It works because Scala can convert `Option` to a `List`, but not in the opposite direction.

In fact it's much more complicated than simple conversion and involves `CanBuildFrom`. Normally monads do not compose at all, but in Scala some do by using `CanBuildFrom`.