# For comprehensions with kotlin and arrow-kt library

Tags: kotlin, io, functional-programming, either, arrow-kt

I use arrow-kt library and I'm trying to employ `Either` and `IO` within the same for comprehension.

Say I have the next piece of code:

```
IO.monad().binding {
    val ans: Either<Error, Data> = someFunctionThatReturnsEitherWrappedInIO().bind()
}
```

Now, I'd like to use binding on the `ans`:

```
val data: Data = ans.bind() // My intent
```

Is it possible to do It whithin the scope of the first piece of code?

Currently I'm trying to nest an `Either` binding within the scope of the IO binding, but I'm not sure this is a good practice:

```
IO.monad().binding {
    val ans: Either<Error, Data> = someFunctionThatReturnsEitherWrappedInIO().bind()
    val ansB: Either<Error, OtherData> = someOtherFunctionThatReturnsEitherWrappedInIO().bind()

    val newData: Either<Any, NewData> = Either.monad<Any>().binding {
        val data: Data = ans.bind()
        val otherData: OtherData = ansB.bind()
        NewData(data.a, otherData.lala)
    }.fix()
}
```

Comment: Monad transformers to the rescue: [`EitherT`](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/arrow/data/eithert/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Background

First I should mention that [Monads don't compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149471/why-do-monads-not-compose-in-scala), that's why you need a [Monad transformer](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html), in your case [`EitherT`](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/arrow/data/eithert/) is the guy that can help you.

### Example

```
object Error

fun one() = IO { Right(1) }
fun two() = IO { Right("2") }
fun toInt(str: String) = IO { Try { str.toInt() }.toEither { Error } }

val result: IO<Either<Error, Int>> =
    EitherT.monad<ForIO, Error>(IO.monad()).binding {
        val oneInt = EitherT(one()).bind()
        val twoString = EitherT(two()).bind()
        val twoInt = EitherT(toInt(twoString)).bind()
        oneInt + twoInt
    }.value().fix()

println(result.unsafeRunSync()) // Just for demonstration, don't do this ever
```

> Right(b=3)