# Defining Monad of nested monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I am trying to define an instance of a monad for a type, which is defined as follows:

```
type Error a = Either String a
data Outer a = Outer { fromOuter :: Error (Maybe a) }
```

*Functors* and *Applicative* instances for the **Outer** type can be defined as:

```
instance Functor Outer where
    f `fmap` (Outer fa) = Outer $ fmap (fmap f) $ fa 


instance Applicative Outer where
     pure = Outer . pure . pure
     (Outer l) <*> (Outer r) = Outer $ do
                             el <- l
                             er <- r
                             return $ el <*> er
```

However, I am struggling to define **bind** for defining *Monad* instance for this type:

```
instance Monad Outer where
    return = pure
    (Outer l) >>= f = ??????
```

Further question is:

How the above can be generalised to, say,

```
data Outer m n a = Outer { fromOuter :: m (n a) }
```

*This problem is an abstraction of a issue in [hedis-simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis-simple-0.1.0.0) where I am trying to define Monad instance for [RedisTx](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis-simple-0.1.0.0/docs/Database-Redis-Simple.html#t:RedisTx)*

Comment: Unfortunatley, monads don't compose. You've discovered a [Monad Transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html)

Comment: It seems hedis-simple defines RedisTx in such a way that it is not possible to write monad instance for it. I wonder if simpler design decisions were possible to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of your `>>=` function should be

```
Outer a -> (a -> Outer b) -> Outer b
```

Since you only have an `a` in the case where the `Outer` value is `(Right (Just x))` for some `x` you can do:

```
instance Monad Outer where
  return = pure
  (Outer l) >>= f = case l of
    Left e -> Outer (Left e)
    Right Nothing -> Outer (Right Nothing)
    Right (Just x) -> f x
```

As for your second question, you can't. Given two monads `M` and `N` their composition `M N` cannot be automatically be made into a monad. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040844/applicatives-compose-monads-dont) for more details.