# Composition of Applicative functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I can compose pure functions:

```
let f x = x + 1
let g x = x + 2
let z = f . g
z 1 == 4
```

I seem to be able to compose monadic functions also:

```
let f x = Just (x + 1)
let g x = Just (x + 2)
let z x = f x >>= g
z 1 == Just 4
```

I think I should be able to treat `f` and `g` from the last example as applicatives and compose those also, just not sure how:

```
let f x = Just (x + 1)
let g x = Just (x + 2)
let z x = f <*> g -- this doesn't work
z 1 == Just 4
```

Is this doable?

Bonus points, can `z x = f x >>= g` be written as a point-free function? Something like `z = f >>= g`?

Comment: This is composition of Kleisli arrows.

Answer (score 6):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
```

The (type-level) composition of any two applicative functors,

```
newtype (f :. g) a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a)) }
```

[is an applicative functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040844/applicatives-compose-monads-dont).

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (f :. g) where
    fmap f = Compose . fmap (fmap f) . getCompose

instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (f :. g) where
    pure = Compose . pure . pure
    Compose fgf <*> Compose fgx = Compose ((<*>) <$> fgf <*> fgx)
```

Your example is the composition of [the `Maybe` applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-633) with [the "function" or "reader" applicative `(->) r`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-617).

```
type ReaderWithMaybe r = ((->) r) :. Maybe

x, y :: ReaderWithMaybe Int Int
x = Compose $ \x -> Just (x + 1)
y = Compose $ \x -> Just (x + 2)
```

Since `ReaderWithMaybe r` is an `Applicative` you can do all the usual `Applicative` stuff. Here I'm smashing my two values together with `+`.

```
ghci> let z = (+) <$> x <*> y
ghci> getCompose z 3
Just 9  -- (3 + 1) + (3 + 2) == 9
```

Note that `x` and `y` both get the *same input* `3`. That's the behaviour of `(->) r`'s `Applicative` instance. If you want to take the *result* of `f x = Just (x + 1)` and feed it into `g x = Just (x + 2)` (to get something equivalent to `h x = Just (x + 3)`), well, that's what `Monad` is for.

---

> Bonus points, can `z x = f x >>= g` be written as a point-free function? Something like `z = f >>= g`?

You can easily define Kleisli composition by hand.

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
f >=> g = \x -> f x >>= g
```

It happens that `>=>` already exists in the standard library, along with its sister `<=<`. They are lovingly known as the "fish" operators, and they live in [`Control.Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-).

Comment: I'm struggling to read this :( - `Compose` and `ReaderWithMaybe` are confusing me. Despite this, the `let z = (+) <$> x <*> y` is interesting because you specify an operator `(+)` to use to compose these two functions together. This is not needed for `f . g` or `f >=> g` which I find a bit odd...

Comment: A trick I use when I'm confused by a `newtype` is simply expanding the definition by hand. You'll see that `ReaderWithMaybe r a` is isomorphic to `r -> Maybe a`.

Comment: And, yes, I'm mapping `+` over my two applicative values. Look at the type: `ReaderWithMaybe Int Int` is a _value_ of type `Int` in the _context_ `ReaderWithMaybe Int`. You can't apply `.` or `>=>` to a pair of `Int`s. If I had, say, `f :: ReaderWithMaybe Int (a -> b)` and `g :: ReaderWithMaybe Int (b -> c)` then I could write `(.) <$> g <*> f`

Answer (score 3):

Applicative functions aren't

```
let f x = Just $ x + 1
let g x = Just $ x + 2
```

, they're

```
let f = Just $ \x -> x + 1
let g = Just $ \x -> x + 2
```

. Composition then works like `liftA2 (.) f g` or `(.) <$> f <*> g`.

Comment: If I use `let f` and `let g` from your answer, then `let z = (.) <$> f <*> g`, I get `Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> t’ with actual type ‘Maybe (Integer -> Integer)’`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: you might need to add an additional type signature (or use named functions with type signatures)

Comment: @epsilonhalbe @Gurkenglas, `f,g :: Int -> Maybe (Int -> Int)`, right? What should be the type for of `z = (.) <$> f <*> g`?

Comment: no `f,g :: Maybe (Int -> Int)` => `z :: Maybe (Int -> Int)`

Comment: Applicative does not work on contained values but only on containers, see what happens if you use `h :: Maybe (Int -> Int); h = Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will be interested by  Kleisli composition of monads:

```
(<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
```