# Swap inner and outer monads

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

How to convert `StateT g (Either E) T` to `ExceptT E (StateT g Identity) T`?

Probably, some mix of `traverse` and `hoist` could be useful here.

Comment: When `StateT g (Either e) t` fails, it doesn't provide any state. What should the corresponding `ExceptT e (StateT g Identity) t` do?

Comment: I can't recall the exact definitions, but can't the first monad fail depending on the state (e.g. if the state is an even number), when the second one can not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[You can't exchange an arbitrary pair of monads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7042674/1523776). But you can exchange these two particular monads. It's easiest to understand if you expand the `newtype`s in the definitions of those monad transformers.

Given

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (s, a) }
```

and

```
newtype ExceptT e m a = ExceptT { runExceptT :: m (Either e a) }
```

expanding the `newtype`s in your first type expression gives us the isomorphism

```
StateT s (Either e) a   <->   s -> Either e (s, a)
```

whereas for the second we get

```
ExceptT e (StateT s Identity) a   <->   s -> (s, Either e a)
```

Note that `Either e (s, a)` may or may not contain an `s`, whereas `(s, Either e a)` always does. Now, one can go from the latter to the former just by `traverse`ing the tuple inside the function, but going the other way requires some domain-specific reasoning: if the computation throws an error then we should plumb the state through unchanged to the catcher of the error. (Is this the right thing to do? I find it rather debatable.)

```
stateTEitherToExceptTState :: (s -> Either e (s, a)) -> (s -> (s, Either e a))
stateTEitherToExceptTState f s =
    case f s of
         Left e -> (s, Left e)
         Right sa -> fmap Right sa
```

Comment: I think `stateTEitherToExceptTState` is not a valid monad morphism. If `m` is an action that doesn't fail, and `f` a Kleisli arrow that always fails, `morph (m >>= f)` is not equal to `morph m >= morph . f`.