# Monad transformer Inner structural order

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have been wondering why Monad Transformers has for example `m(Maybe(m(Maybe a))` structural order and why not `Maybe(m(Maybe( m a)))`. I have tried to implement the second one but I'm unable to complete it possibly BCS of my inadequate Haskell knowledge.

In all monad transformers, do we always have a structure like this?
if yes then why?
if not then when to choose one from another?

```
newtype MaybeOT m a = MaybeOT {runMaybeOT :: Maybe (m  a) }
instance (Monad m) => Monad (MaybeOT m) where
return = pure
(MaybeOT mma) >>= f = MaybeOT $ 
                        case mma of
                            Nothing -> Nothing
                            (Just ma) -> inner ma where
                                         inner ma = do
                                            a <- ma
                                            undefined
```

Comment: did you mean `where inner ma = ...` instead of `let`?

Comment: I implemented [an `Applicative` instance](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/manifolds/blob/6f4d3ed71497074ad4cef2874a2d9fe73a14a377/manifolds/Control/Monad/Trans/OuterMaybe.hs) for this at some point, but not even sure if it's law-conforming.

Comment: @WillNess fixed example code

Comment: The primary problem will arise from the fact that, at the end of the day - you must perform `bind`/`>>=` on the type `m a`. Yet, you're given a function that returns the type `MaybeOT (m b)`. Of course, `bind` on `m a` must be given a function that returns `m b`, for whatever `b`. You can get `Maybe (m a)` from `MaybeOT (m b)`. But what next? The outwards monad's information is all you have, and it's the information you require to implement monadic composition (transformers) - yet you're required to throw it away in this step.

Comment: In contrast, for `MaybeT`, where `Maybe` is the inner monad. You bind on `m (Maybe a)` once. Here, you have the chance to inspect the inner `Maybe` for `Nothing`. In that case, `pure` helps you construct the outer monad. Furthermore, the function you're given returns `MaybeT m b`. You can get `m (Maybe b)` from that - which is precisely what you need to successfully `bind` on `m (Maybe a)`. And thus, it works nicely. You've used the information about `Maybe` and what exactly it represents within the implementation, instead of having to throw it away.

Comment: It helps to notice that the primary problem you face with `MaybeOT` is that you're stuck with `Maybe (m a)` where you needed `m (Maybe a)`. [This is also the primary problem you face when implementing `bind` for *arbitrary nested monads*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7042674/10305477). Hence, the need for monad transformers. Interestingly, [traversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html) monads have the ability to interchange outer and inner contexts - thus allowing them to bypass all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've essentially discovered why monad transformers are *inwards* instead of *outwards* (nit: I'm pretty sure I'm not using correct terminology here, but you get what I mean - feel free to correct me here). It's much easier (easy == less constraints) to have *the monad you know about* be in the **data position** (inside), rather than the **container position** (outside). Intuitively, you can see why - after all, the monadic nature demands the **container** to be the same. You can do whatever you want with the data, but you must not change the type of the container during binding.

Of course, it's easier to realize all this by actually trying to implement the absurd. Which is what this is about. The final step you'll be stuck on while implementing `>>=`/`bind` for `MaybeOT` is this-

```hs
m a >>= ??? . runMaybeOT . f
```

Where, `m` is a `Monad`, `m a :: m a`, `f :: a -> MaybeOT m a`, and `runMaybeOT :: MaybeOT m a -> Maybe (m a)` (and also `??? :: ???`, hehe)

Now, you must obtain a monad with the container type `m` to successfully bind on `m a`. But alas, you cannot get the `m a` out of `Maybe (m a)`! What happens when it's `Nothing`? Your primary tool in implementing monad transformers is *knowledge* about the **specific monad** you're implementing the transformer for. And your knowledge is telling you that this is absurd.

In contrast, the final step in implementing `>>=` for `MaybeT` goes well smoothly. For completeness, here's `MaybeT`-

```hs
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

Here, you'll be binding on the type `m (Maybe a)`. During binding, you must return the type `m b`, for whatever `b`. You're given a function, `f`, of type `a -> MaybeT m b`, you can easily get `m (Maybe b)` from `MaybeT m b`.

Aha! Now you can see the solution. The function you're given *returns* the *same outer monad* as the *one you're binding on*. That is precisely what you need. In the case of `MaybeOT`, you were stuck with binding on the monad `m`, with a function that doesn't return a value with outer monad `m`!

And that is the crucial realization - the function you're given must be able to give you a value with the same outer monad. This is why `MaybeT` (and other transformers too) keeps the unknown monad outwards - because when you implement `>>=` for `MaybeT`, you know the binding function will be required to construct that outer monad.

It is helpful, at least intuitively, to note that the problem you get stuck on here - is the very same problem you'll face when implementing monadic composition. That is, `>>=` for nested monads. [Monads don't compose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7042674/10305477)! That's why you need monad transformers!

If you break this problem down, you'll notice that if you just had a function that could *swap* monads, to get `Maybe (m a)` from `m (Maybe a)` and vice versa - all would be well. Monads would compose, monad transformers could look like however you please, and in fact, monad transformers would essentially serve no purpose. This detail is noticed [in the answer linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040844/applicatives-compose-monads-dont/7042674#7042674). All you need is-

```hs
swap :: (Monad m, Monad n) => m (n a) -> n (m a)
```

[This *exists*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequence). They're called traversable monads, and indeed if you merely add the `Traversable` constraint to your `Monad` implementation for `MaybeOT`, you strike gold-

```hs
instance (Traversable m, Monad m) => Monad (MaybeOT m) where
    return = pure
    MaybeOT Nothing >>= _   = MaybeOT Nothing
    MaybeOT (Just ma) >>= f = MaybeOT $ sequence $ ma >>= sequence . runMaybeOT . f
```

I *assume* it's law-conforming, though I'd have to check.

In another note, it is totally possible to make `MaybeOT` a law conforming applicative. After all, the problem you face while implementing `Monad` is simply non existent here. Applicatives *do* compose.

```hs
instance Applicative f => Applicative (MaybeT f) where
    pure = MaybeT . pure . Just
    MaybeT f <*> MaybeT a = MaybeT $ liftA2 (<*>) f a
```

(Or, perhaps more simply)

```
instance Applicative f => Applicative (MaybeT f) where
    pure = MaybeT . pure . Just
    MaybeT f <*> MaybeT a = MaybeT $ (<*>) <$> f <*> a
```

Which *should* be law conforming, as far as I can tell.